# Automate Company selection after login in Quickbooks

Tags: python, django, flask, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have to authenticate QuickBooks in flask. all things are working proper.
But once generate AUTH URL run that URL in browser, then need to select company. is there any way to skip company selection or automate company select.
I don't want to select company.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHhjv.png)

I don't want this screen, How can I select company auto?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to skip that screen.

(Though worth noting - if the user only has access to a single QuickBooks Online company, which will be the case for most people, then that screen does not appear at all.)